# Using Pyinstaller for the joblib(parallelism) in Windows not running it

Tags: windows, pyqt5, pyinstaller, joblib

I made a python application using [Joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) and created a windows package using Pyinstaller then my application just frozen and not working. Actually, it creates the 4 UI instance(4 because of the number of jobs is 4) and all four just froze.

Wondering how to bundle the pyqt5+joblib in windows, any help appreciated?

This is the command I used to create the bundle.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.py
```

---

Without bundle it works well without any problem.

This is how my main method looks like.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    # After adding this piece of code it just close the frozen app
    if sys.argv[0][-4:] == '.exe':
        setattr(sys, 'frozen', True)
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Coderji nope, I abandoned using joblib, instead used pyqt threads, using pyqt threads I can able to create .exe.